# Centering TikZ picture inside poster box

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, baposter

I would like to center a tikzpicture inside a posterbox (`baposter`)

```
\headerbox{Vorgehensweise}{name=definitions,column=3,below=problem,span=3}{

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,calc,calc,shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows,fit,backgrounds,positioning}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]


\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{pro} = [rectangle, minimum width=10cm, minimum height=5cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!40]
\tikzstyle{brown} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=brown!30]
\tikzstyle{blue} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!20]

\begin{minipage}{10em}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',scale=1.3, every node/.style={scale=1.13},anchor=center]

\node (start) [startstop] {Theoretische Exploration und Verortung};


\node  (pro1) [pro,below= 0.3cm of start] {};
\node at ($(pro1) + (0,1.9)$)    {\textbf{Empirische Exploration}};

\node (qual) [decision, below left of=pro1, yshift=1.8cm, xshift=-1.076cm ] {Quant. Erfassung mittels Fragebögen};
\node (quant) [decision, below right of=pro1, yshift=0.3cm, xshift=1.2cm] {Qual. Erfassung mittels Interviews};
\node (dec1) [blue, below of=pro1, yshift=-1.cm] {Modellierung der ÜNOLS};
\node (dec2) [brown, below of=dec1, yshift=-0.3cm] {Konsequenzen und Perspektiven};
%\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]


  \path (qual.south) edge [bend right] node {} (dec1.west)
        (start) edge  node {} (pro1)
        (qual.east) edge [bend left]  node {} (quant.north)
        (quant) edge [bend left
] node {} (dec1.east)
        (pro1) edge  node {} (dec2);
%\draw [arrow] (start) -- (pro1);
%\draw [arrow] (qual.east) -- (quant.north);
%\draw [arrow] (qual.south) --  (dec1.west);
%\draw [arrow] (quant) --  (dec1.east);
%\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (dec2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{minipage}

}
```

The picture stays flushed left ... minipage and `\centeing` doesnt help. Do you have any ideas? Thanks! :)

Comment: Please turn your snippet into a *complete* minimal document illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You used `\centering` within the `minipage`.

Instead, use `\centering` at the outer level, or `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` at outer level, i.e. not within the mini page.

Another approach would be centering using the `current page` node in TikZ for reference.